# Creating s3 presigned url

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am attempting to create presigned urls's to documents for a client that will be downloading them via a browser. We are using aws kms signing.

After searching in vain for a way to generate these via the cli, I settled on using the java sdk using the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html). It generates a link but I get the following error.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.
</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>blah</RequestId>
<HostId>blah
</HostId>
</Error>
```

However, my profile has that specification:

```
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
```

I'm not sure what other options I need to specify. I found a few options including setting the following and passing it to the client constructor:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType");
```

To no avail. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are some examples here: https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1518K5RPDEG0B/Generating-Amazon-S3-Pre-signed-URLs-with-SSE-KMS-Part-2 Maybe compare your code with the example pre-signed GETs on that page?